# Setting a char array with c_str()?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, c-str

```
char el[3] = myvector[1].c_str();
```

`myvector[i]` is a string with three letters in. Why does this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns type char* which is a pointer to a string. You can't assign this directly to an array like that, as that array already has memory assigned to it. Try:

```
const char* el = myvector[1].c_str();
```

But very careful if the string itself is destroyed or changed as the pointer will no longer be valid.

Comment: Not only if the string is destroyed - the pointer will also be invalidated if the string is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `const char *` is not a valid initializer for an array. What's more, I believe `c_str` returns a pointer to internal memory so it's not safe to store.

You probably want to copy the value in some way (`memcpy` or `std::copy` or something else).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said, keep in mind that a string with a length of three characters requires four bytes when converted to a c_str. This is because an extra byte has to be reserved for the null at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C++ must know their size, and be provided with initialisers, at compile-time. The value returned by c_str() is only known at run-time. If e1 were a std::string, as it probably should be, there would be no problem. If it must be a char[], then use strcpy to populate it.

```
char el[3];
strcpy( e1, myvector[1].c_str() );
```

This assumes that the string myvector[1] contains at most two characters.

Comment: `std::copy(myvector[1].begin(), myvector[1].begin() + 3, e1)` doesn't require any assumption!

Comment: @Nawaz It assumes the OP does not want the result to be null-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a copy of the string. Then, if you ever need to access it as a char*, just do so.

```
string el = myvector[1];
cout << &el[0] << endl;
```

Make the string const if you don't need to modify it. Use c_str() on 'el' instead if you want.

Or, just access it right from the vector with:

```
cout << &myvector[1][0] << endl;
```

if possible for your situation.